# Pandas: change cell values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id_a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], 'name_a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
        'id_b': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11], 'name_b': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'k'], 
        'similar': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 'metric': [.5, 1, .8, .7, .2, .9, .8, .9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

⠀

```
      id_a   name_a   id_b   name_b   similar   metric  
 --- ------ -------- ------ -------- --------- -------- 
  0    1       a       5       e         1       0.5    
  1    1       a       6       f         1       1.0    
  2    1       a       7       g         1       0.8    
  3    2       b       8       h         1       0.7    
  4    2       b       9       i         1       0.2    
  5    2       b       10      j         0       0.9    
  6    3       c       11      k         1       0.8    
  7    4       d       11      k         1       0.9
```

In this table, the IDs of group A are linked to the IDs of group B (based on column `similar`).

But I need a unique ID of each group to correspond to only one ID of another group.

And among the rows with the same ID of each group, I need to select the row in which the column `metric` is maximum.

For example, I have three rows with `id_a` == 2. Among these three rows, only two have a column `similar` value equal to 1.
Among these two rows, one row has a column `metric` value of 0.7, and the second one has 0.2.

I leave the value of column `similar` = 1, only for the row with a column `metric` of 0.7 (because it is maximum), and for the second row I put the value of column `similar` = 0.

That is, I need the following dataframe:

```
output_data = {'id_a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], 'name_a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
               'id_b': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11], 'name_b': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'k'], 
               'similar': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'metric': [.5, 1, .8, .7, .2, .9, .8, .9]}
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
print(output_df)
```

⠀

```
      id_a   name_a   id_b   name_b   similar   metric  
 --- ------ -------- ------ -------- --------- -------- 
  0    1       a       5       e         0       0.5    
  1    1       a       6       f         1       1.0    
  2    1       a       7       g         0       0.8    
  3    2       b       8       h         1       0.7    
  4    2       b       9       i         0       0.2    
  5    2       b       10      j         0       0.9    
  6    3       c       11      k         0       0.8    
  7    4       d       11      k         1       0.9
```

**Question:** How to implement this using Python (because my research did not give any results)?

Comment: Why row 6 similar becomes 0?

Comment: Because there are two rows with `id_b` == 11 (row 6 and row 7), and row 7 `metric`  is bigger than row 6 `metric`

Comment: So id_b must be considered also?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, yes

Comment: @lemon, but aren't they in different boats since they have different `id_a`s? Can you explain a bit more on the constraint under which we compare `metric` between two columns?

Comment: Among the rows with the same `id_a`, we select the row with the maximum value of the column `metric`, and among the rows, with the same `id_b` we select the row with the maximum value of the column `metric`.

Comment: @lemon, hmm the problem with that is: what if a row is the max `metric` in a group when we constrain with `id_a` but not with `id_b`? Should the row's `similar` column be assigned to 0 or 1? It depends on the order you choose to run things in. If you're confident it doesn't mater in your use case, then you can easily run my answer twice, constraining on `id_b` the second time.

Comment: @BrianJoseph, unfortunately, during the second run for `id_b` it returns `ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence`

Comment: @lemon, as to not draw out the comments section, please see the comments section on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use groupby `idxmax`, `isin` and on 2 groupby's within the listcomp and passing to `np.array`. Finally, call `all` and `astype` on `np.array`

```
df1 = df[df.similar.eq(1)]
df['similar'] = np.array([df.index.isin(df1.groupby(col).metric.idxmax()) 
                            for col in ['id_a', 'id_b']]).all(0).astype(int)


Out[132]:
   id_a name_a  id_b name_b  similar  metric
0     1      a     5      e        0     0.5
1     1      a     6      f        1     1.0
2     1      a     7      g        0     0.8
3     2      b     8      h        1     0.7
4     2      b     9      i        0     0.2
5     2      b    10      j        0     0.9
6     3      c    11      k        0     0.8
7     4      d    11      k        1     0.9
```

Comment: This output does not match what was expected, you have not taken into account id_b

Comment: @ansev: I came up with this on the way going away from the computer. I quickly looked at the other high voted answer to compare my output, so I didn't notice. Anyway, I edited the answer to account for `id_b` :)

Comment: I think the right thing is that the correct and scalable solutions are rewarded :)

Comment: @ansev: Thanks. Yours is good, too. I don't understand why someone downvoted yours. I upvoted yours :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how you're handling the case of `id_a == 3` for instnace but I think this is what you want. Just take the max index from each group (grouped by `id_a`) and then, after resetting the `similar` column, reset those maximal indexes to 1.

```
max_vals = df.groupby('id_a').apply(lambda grp: grp.loc[grp['similar'] == 1, 'metric'].idxmax())
df['similar'] = 0
df.loc[max_vals, 'similar'] = 1

>>> df

    id_a    name_a  id_b    name_b  similar metric
0   1       a       5       e       0       0.5
1   1       a       6       f       1       1.0
2   1       a       7       g       0       0.8
3   2       b       8       h       1       0.7
4   2       b       9       i       0       0.2
5   2       b       10      j       0       0.9
6   3       c       11      k       1       0.8
7   4       d       11      k       1       0.9
```

**EDIT**: See the comments as to why the output doesn't match exactly for row #6.

Comment: OP, if you need to run it again on `id_b`, then you need to make sure that every group has at least one value of `similar` that is 1: `df.groupby('id_b').filter(lambda grp: 1 in grp['similar'].values)`. Then you should be able to run it twice.

Comment: This is not the expected output provided by OP.Also this seems inefficient

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could do:

```
# find the indices of the maximum by id_a
keep_a = df[df.similar.eq(1)].groupby('id_a').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).groupby('id_a').metric.idxmax()

# find the indices of the maximum by id_b
keep_b = df[df.similar.eq(1)].groupby('id_b').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1).groupby('id_b').metric.idxmax()

# create mask False if is in set of maximum
mask = ~df.index.isin(set(keep_a) | set(keep_b))

# set values using mask
df.loc[mask, 'similar'] = 0

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id_a name_a  id_b name_b  similar  metric
0     1      a     5      e        0     0.5
1     1      a     6      f        1     1.0
2     1      a     7      g        0     0.8
3     2      b     8      h        1     0.7
4     2      b     9      i        0     0.2
5     2      b    10      j        0     0.9
6     3      c    11      k        0     0.8
7     4      d    11      k        1     0.9
```

Comment: What would happen here if there were more ids?

Comment: What do you mean by more ids? A third column `id_c` for example?

Comment: I wanted to say more ids and more names, not just a and b (ie N instead of 2), would you have to group N times?

Comment: @ansev I believe so, but I don't a workaround to that.

Answer (score 2):

## **Here is a clear symmetrical, orderly and fast way to do this task.**

- [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) 
  to transform the value of `metric` into `NaN` where `similar == 0` so that it can never be the maximum and therefore have a 1 in the result.
- [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) to be able to group when there are either consecutive values ​​in `id_a` or in `id_b`. Keep in mind that this would be that simple for N ids.
- create a series with the maximums by groups using `groupby.transform` and compare it with the `Metric` Series to obtain a Boolean series that you can convert with [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `1` or `0`

---

```
df2=df.copy()
#discarding similar == 0 as a maximum candidate in the groups
df2['metric']=df2['metric'].mask(df2['similar'].eq(0))

#creating groups depend on id_a and id_b
ids=df2[['id_a','id_b']]
groups=ids.ne(ids.shift()).all(axis=1).cumsum()

#checking the maximum per group and converting to integer
df['similar']=df['metric'].eq(df2.groupby(groups).metric.transform('max')).astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

**Output**

```
   id_a name_a  id_b name_b  similar  metric
0     1      a     5      e        0     0.5
1     1      a     6      f        1     1.0
2     1      a     7      g        0     0.8
3     2      b     8      h        1     0.7
4     2      b     9      i        0     0.2
5     2      b    10      j        0     0.9
6     3      c    11      k        0     0.8
7     4      d    11      k        1     0.9
```

---

**Detail of groups**

```
print(groups)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution which uses vectorized methods only.

- `m1`: vector with `max` values per group and `similar == 1`
- `m2`: rows where `similar == 1`
- `m3`: rows which have `max` value & `similar == 1`

```
m1 = df.query('similar == 1').groupby('id_a')['metric'].transform('max')
m2 = df['similar'].eq(1)
m3 = df.loc[m2, 'metric'].eq(m1)

df.loc[m3[~m3].index, 'similar'] = 0
```

```
   id_a name_a  id_b name_b  similar  metric
0     1      a     5      e        0    0.50
1     1      a     6      f        1    1.00
2     1      a     7      g        0    0.80
3     2      b     8      h        1    0.70
4     2      b     9      i        0    0.20
5     2      b    10      j        0    0.90
6     3      c    11      k        1    0.80
7     4      d    11      k        1    0.90
```

Comment: This solution is not equal to the expected output

Comment: I think that this script we can rerun for `id_b`. Just change `groupby('id_a')` to `groupby('id_b')` - and we receive the expected output.

Comment: Hmm I thought it was a typo, also considering the other answers output. @DanielMesejo

Comment: yeah, it was my fault - I did not initially describe the case with `id_b`